# How to remove "image_picker" mark when select image using Image Picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, imagepicker

I have this image picker But when picked the image It shows the "image_pick" mark in front of the image file Like this `image_picker5431631000176511341.jpg` But I want to remove it How can I do that is it possible?

code:

```
//Pick image
ElevatedButton(
         onPressed: () => selectFile(),
         child: const Text(
         'Select Image /Gallery'),
        ),

//Show fileName
Text('$fileName')


//To pick image
  void selectFile() async {
    final XFile? results = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (results != null) {
      path = results.path;

      fileName = results.name;
      setState(() {});
      print(fileName);
    } else {
      print('No image picked');
    }
    setState(() {
      imageFile = File(results!.path);
    });
  }
```

Image:

[image]

remove the "image_picker" mark in front of the actual file name

Comment: you mean the file name to be without the .jpg ?

Comment: I mean without "image_picker" mark. But I've tried your code and it worked Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this

```
fileName = results.name.replaceFirst ("image_picker","");
```